# Coordinate Transformation

Tags: coordinate-transformation

I'm trying to define a module (in Mathematica) that receives a point $\mathbf{p}(\mathbf{x})\in\mathbb{R}^n$ (expressed in the coordinate system $\mathbf{x}$) and a coordinate transformation $\bar{\mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{x})$ as inputs, and returns $\mathbf{p}(\bar{\mathbf{x}})$ as output; i.e., the module will return the point $\mathbf{p}$ expressed in the new coordinate system $\bar{\mathbf{x}}$.

Example: If $\mathbf{p}=(-1,1)$ in cartesian coordinates ($\mathbf{x}=(x,y)$) and $\bar{\mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{x})=(\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\arctan_2(y,x))$ (i.e., $\bar{\mathbf{x}}=(r,\theta)$), then the expected output is $(\sqrt{2},3\pi/4)$. If $\mathbf{p}=(1,2,3)$ in cartesian coordinates and $\bar{\mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{x})=(y+x,y-x,z-1)$, then the expected output is $(3,1,2)$. I want the module to work with a *general* coordinate transformation and dimension.

I feel like I tried everything. The module should be extremely simple, it's just that the syntax confuses me. How do I receive a function as an input? If the module reads "$f(x,y)"$, how do I connect between $x$ and $y$ to the first and second coordinate of $\mathbf{p}$ respectively?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. As phrased, this is a math problem but if you would like to do it using the software called Mathematica then please take a look at this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbpuy.png). Best of luck.

Comment: I'm familiar with the function, but I wanna do it with a general coordinate transformation, not only polar.

Comment: You could also just write a function? Which will work for any transformation depending on how you define it. `transform[{x_, y_}] := {Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]}; p = {-1, 1}; transform[p]` which gives `{Sqrt[2], (3 Pi)/4}`

Comment: @Nasser I can but this is not what I am required to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

coordTransform[pt_List, transform_] :=
 Module[{var = Variables[Level[transform, {-1}]], f},
  f = Function @@ {var, transform}; f @@ pt]

coordTransform[{-1, 1}, {Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]}]

(* {Sqrt[2], (3 π)/4} *)

coordTransform[{1, 2, 3}, {y + x, y - x, z - 1}]

(* {3, 1, 2} *)
```

**EDIT:** The original response assumed that the variables associated with `pt` where in canonical order (e.g., {x, y, z}}. The results would be wrong if they were not. To allow for arbitrarily ordered variables, an **optional** argument is necessary.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

coordTransform[pt_List, transform_, var_ : Automatic] := 
 Module[{v, f},
  v = If[var === Automatic, Variables[Level[transform, {-1}]], var];
  f = Function @@ {v, transform};
  f @@ pt]
```

For canonical variables the use and results are the same.

```
coordTransform[{1, 2, 3}, {y + x, y - x, z - 1}]

(* {3, 1, 2} *)
```

However, for non-canonical variables the order must be provided. For example, if `pt` represents `{x, y, c}` (non-canonical order) then

```
coordTransform[{1, 2, 3}, {y + x, y - x, c - 1}, {x, y, c}]

(* {3, 1, 2} *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3):

Is this what the OP desires?

```
Clear[coordtransfed]
coordtransfed[oldcoords_, transffunc_] := transffunc[oldcoords]
```

```
coordtransfed[{-1, 1}, ToPolarCoordinates]
coordtransfed[{1, 2, 3}, ({x, y, z} \[Function] {y + x, y - x, z - 1}) @@ # &]
```

> ```
> {Sqrt[2], (3 \[Pi])/4}
> ```

> ```
> {3, 1, 2}
> ```